# Combining if error with offset for a Dynamic named range in excel?

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I am having a situation where i download data from an api (takes a few seconds each time).
Then i use a named range in excel using the following code

```
=OFFSET(DATA_PER_YEAR!$A$8;COUNTA(DATA_PER_YEAR!$A$8:$A$100)-DATA_PER_YEAR!$H$1;0;DATA_PER_YEAR!$H$1;1)
```

Where DATA_PER_YEAR!$H$1 is a variable to give the size of the "window" to return. I then use the named range to create plots.
This works very well until I refresh the api and then there is no data in the cells for a few seconds. This gives a lot of error messages, so in order to fix it i tried to wrap a iferror(code,indirect("a8:a9")) but that did not seam to work.
Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest you make sure the range is always at least one cell by adding something like MAX: `MAX(1;COUNTA(DATA_PER_YEAR!$A$8:$A$100)-DATA_PER_YEAR!$H$1)`

Comment: very good idea. Thanks alot!